# What's the best freely available C# wrapper for BITS?

Tags: c#, windows, interop, microsoft-bits

BITS, the Windows background intelligent transfer service.

Looks like there are a few C# wrappers around that manage the interop to BITS, does anybody have any opinions on the best one?

Comment: There's a new [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bits-dot-net) page that talks about using BITS and C#, plus a brand-new c#/WPF sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/bits-manager).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found problems with using the Managed_BITS codeproject article and I found an even better wrapper:

http://www.codeplex.com/sharpbits
http://nuget.org/packages/SharpBITS

Less code, a lot cleaner and unlike the codeproject, it did not hide away those parts of the BITS interface that I actually need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Managed_BITS.aspx
2. http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/using-bits-to-upload-files-with-.net/